# how to use Sed to add spicial charectar?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

how to use Sed to add spicial charectar ?

script shell:              the chalange is:

I have a large file xx.html:

...
...
...

my quastion is how can I use sed command to insert this line:
secure_token = ''
function getipInfo()

to xx.html file before

```
</body>  line


I try to much scinario , alwase there is issue in php charectar 

sed -i '102i secure_token = \'\<\?php \e\cho file_get_contents\(\"token.txt\"\); \?\>\'\n
   function getipInfo()' xx.html
```

Answer (score 0):

how to insert

```
 secure_token = '<?php echo file_get_contents("token.txt"); ?>'    function getipInfo()
```

into a file using sed

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert this line before `</body>`:

```bash
sed -i '/^<\/body>/i  secure_token = \x27<?php echo file_get_contents("token\.txt"); ?>\x27    function getipInfo()' xx.html
```